# Filtering noise from very noisy binary thresholded image

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I would like to be able to analyze the following image, get the lines and find the average width.(My copy is much larger ~5K by ~4K) Cannot move to the next step due to all the noise after thresholding.

[image]

Using my code I was able to get to this point...

[image]

My issue is that it has a lot of noise in-between lines, which looks like noise that got condensed.

Here is my code...

```
image = np.copy(origImg)
newImage = np.empty_like(image)

scale = 64

height = image.shape[0]
width = image.shape[1]

dH = int(height / scale)
dW = int(width / scale)

xi = int(dH)
yi = int(dW)

fragments = []
image = cv2.bilateralFilter(image,9,75,75)
image = cv2.medianBlur(image, 21)

for i in range(0,height,dH):
    for j in range(0,width,dW):
        fragment = image[i:i + int(dH), j:j + int(dW)]

        fragment = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(fragment, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY, 31, 0)

        fragments.append(fragment)

analyzed = com.stackArrayToImage(fragments)

nlabels, labels, stats, centroids = cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats(analyzed, None, None, None, 8, cv2.CV_32S)
sizes = stats[1:, -1] 
img2 = np.zeros((labels.shape), np.uint8)

for i in range(0, nlabels - 1):
    if sizes[i] >= 100:  
        img2[labels == i + 1] = 255

analyzed = cv2.bitwise_not(img2)

analyzed = cv2.erode(analyzed, np.ones((5, 5)), iterations=2)
analyzed = cv2.dilate(analyzed, np.ones((5, 5), np.uint8))

dis.plotImages([origImg], "Origional")
dis.plotImages([analyzed], "Analyzed")
dis.displayStart()
```

Is there anyway I can remove that noise?

Thank you very much!

Comment: You can use morphological operations (https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_morphological_ops/py_morphological_ops.html). It will not make miracles, but it is a pretty start to filter this noise.

Comment: Yes, I tried it. Did not do much sadly.

Comment: Even though your lines are curved, you can find the dominant line segments using [Hough Transform](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_houghlines/py_houghlines.html) or a [Line Segment Detector](https://docs.opencv.org/trunk/db/d73/classcv_1_1LineSegmentDetector.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove some of the noise using contour area filtering with [`cv2.contourArea`](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#contourarea). The idea is to filter using some threshold area. If a contour passes this filter then we can remove the noise by filling in the contour with [`cv2.drawContours`](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_contours/py_contours_begin/py_contours_begin.html#how-to-draw-the-contours). Using your binary image as input:

[image]

Detected contours to remove highlighted in green

[image]

Result

[image]

Depending on how much noise you want to remove, you can adjust the threshold area value

Code

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

# Load image, grayscale, Otsu's threshold
image = cv2.imread("1.png")
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

# Find contours and filter using contour area
cnts = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
for c in cnts:
    area = cv2.contourArea(c)
    if area < 50:
        cv2.drawContours(thresh, [c], -1, 0, -1)
        cv2.drawContours(image, [c], -1, (36,255,12), -1)

result = 255 - thresh
cv2.imshow("image", image) 
cv2.imshow("thresh", thresh) 
cv2.imshow("result", result) 
cv2.waitKey()
```